# Using Mathematica remotely via SSH and PuTTY

Tags: linux-mint, x11, tmux, remote, putty

I would like to run Mathematica notebooks on a remote Linux Mint machine.
What I do:

1. Connect Via VPN to the university network
2. Start xLaunch (xMing)
3. Start PuTTY and enable X11 forwarding (connect via SSH)
4. start a new session with tmux and run mathematica which due to xLaunch opens in a window
5. Open my mathematica file which I previouly copied to the Linux Mint machine.
6. Evaluate it.

Problems:

1. Mathematica lags like hell, I can't even scroll and editing the file is no fun.
2. If I loose my internet connection and try reconnecting to my tmux session I get this error message:
   "Mathematica has received the signal: SIGSEGV and has exited."

Questions:

1. Is there a better and lag free way of editing/running mathematica files remotely ?
2. How can I make sure that I can reconnect to my session without killing mathematica?